# How to check if a function is decorated with a specific decorator?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-decorators

I want to check if a Python function is decorated, and store the decorator parameter in the function dict. This is my code:

```
from functools import wraps

def applies_to(segment="all"):
    def applies(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            func.func_dict["segment"] = segment
            print func.__name__
            print func.func_dict
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return applies
```

But looks like the dict is lost:

```
@applies_to(segment="mysegment")
def foo():
    print "Some function"


> foo() # --> Ok, I get the expected result
foo
{'segment': 'mysegment'}

> foo.__dict__ # --> Here I get empty result. Why is the dict empty?
{}
```

Comment: You're modifying the wrong function, at the wrong time.

Comment: Should I modify "applies" function at run time?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, thanks to [user2357112](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2357112/user2357112)'s clue, I found the answer. Even with an improvement

```
from functools import wraps

def applies_to(*segments):
    def applies(func):
        func.func_dict["segments"] = list(segments)
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return applies
```

Thanks!

Comment: In Python 3 the `func_dict` attribute has been renamed to `__dict__`. You also need to change the `*segments` to `**segements` in order to use `@applies_to(segment="mysegment")`.