# Check which decorator was applied to a function

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68583870/checking-whether-a-function-is-decorated?noredirect=1&lq=1) I have an idea how to check whether my function was decorated or not.

Only that I need further information, namely the decorators that were actually applied onto the function (or called when the function was called if it suits better).

For being safe from the danger [mentioned in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73769181/6560773), I am using `functools.wraps`. This way I don't have to be careful for any naming redefinition of the wrapper used.

This is what I have so far:

```py
from functools import wraps

def decorator_wraps(function):
    @wraps(function)
    def _wrapper(*a, **kw): ...
    return _wrapper

def is_decorated(func):
    return hasattr(func, '__wrapped__')

@decorator_wraps
def foo(x, y): ...

print(is_decorated(foo))  # True
```

But what I need:

```py
from functools import wraps

def decorator_wraps_1(function):
    @wraps(function)
    def _wrapper(*a, **kw): ...
    return _wrapper

def decorator_wraps_2(function):
    @wraps(function)
    def _wrapper(*a, **kw): ...
    return _wrapper

def decorators(func):
    # returns list of decorators on `func`

# OR

def is_decorated_by(func, decorator):
    # returns True if `func` is decorated by `decorator`

@decorator_wraps_1
@decorator_wraps_2
def foo(x, y): ...

print(decorators(foo))  # [decorator_wraps_1, decorator_wraps_2]
print(is_decorated_by(foo, decorator_wraps_1))  # True
```

**TLDR**

I want to decide if my function was decorated and I need the names of these decorator functions as well.

Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: Related but probably needs an updated answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232024/introspection-to-get-decorator-names-on-a-method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## TL;DR

Roll your own `@wraps`.

```py
import functools

def update_wrapper(wrapper, wrapped, decorator, **kwargs):
    wrapper = functools.update_wrapper(wrapper, wrapped, **kwargs)
    if decorator is not None:
        __decorators__ = getattr(wrapper, "__decorators__", [])
        setattr(wrapper, "__decorators__", __decorators__ + [decorator])
    return wrapper

def wraps(wrapped, decorator, **kwargs):
    return functools.partial(
        update_wrapper, wrapped=wrapped, decorator=decorator, **kwargs
    )

def get_decorators(func):
    return getattr(func, "__decorators__", [])

def is_decorated_by(func, decorator):
    return decorator in get_decorators(func)
```

Usage:

```py
def test_decorator_1(function):
    @wraps(function, test_decorator_1)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return function(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

def test_decorator_2(function):
    @wraps(function, test_decorator_2)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return function(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

@test_decorator_1
@test_decorator_2
def foo(x: str, y: int) -> None:
    print(x, y)

assert get_decorators(foo) == [test_decorator_2, test_decorator_1]
assert is_decorated_by(foo, test_decorator_1)
```

## Custom `@wraps`

#### Concept

There is no built-in way for this as far as I know. All it takes to create a (functional) decorator is to define a function that takes another function as argument and returns a function. No information about that "outer" function is magically imprinted onto the returned function by virtue of decoration.

However we can lean on the [`functools.wraps`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.wraps) approach and simply roll our own variation of it. We can define it in such a way that it takes not just a reference to the wrapped function as argument, but also a reference to the outer decorator.

The same way that [`functools.update_wrapper`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.update_wrapper) defines the additional `__wrapped__` attribute on the wrapper it outputs, we can define our own custom `__decorators__` attribute, which will be simply a list of all the decorators in the order of application (the reverse order of notation).

#### Code

The proper type annotations are a bit tricky, but here is a full working example:

```py
import functools
from collections.abc import Callable
from typing import Any, ParamSpec, TypeAlias, TypeVar


P = ParamSpec("P")
T = TypeVar("T")
AnyFunc: TypeAlias = Callable[..., Any]


def update_wrapper(
    wrapper: Callable[P, T],
    wrapped: AnyFunc,
    decorator: AnyFunc | None = None,
    assigned: tuple[str, ...] = functools.WRAPPER_ASSIGNMENTS,
    updated: tuple[str, ...] = functools.WRAPPER_UPDATES,
) -> Callable[P, T]:
    """
    Same as `functools.update_wrapper`, but can also add `__decorators__`.

    If provided a `decorator` argument, it is appended to the the
    `__decorators__` attribute of `wrapper` before returning it.
    If `wrapper` has no `__decorators__` attribute, a list with just
    `decorator` in it is created and set as that attribute on `wrapper`.
    """
    wrapper = functools.update_wrapper(
        wrapper,
        wrapped,
        assigned=assigned,
        updated=updated,
    )
    if decorator is not None:
        __decorators__ = getattr(wrapper, "__decorators__", [])
        setattr(wrapper, "__decorators__", __decorators__ + [decorator])
    return wrapper


def wraps(
    wrapped: AnyFunc,
    decorator: AnyFunc | None,
    assigned: tuple[str, ...] = functools.WRAPPER_ASSIGNMENTS,
    updated: tuple[str, ...] = functools.WRAPPER_UPDATES
) -> Callable[[Callable[P, T]], Callable[P, T]]:
    """Same as `functools.wraps`, but uses custom `update_wrapper` inside."""
    return functools.partial(
        update_wrapper,  # type: ignore[arg-type]
        wrapped=wrapped,
        decorator=decorator,
        assigned=assigned,
        updated=updated,
    )


def get_decorators(func: AnyFunc) -> list[AnyFunc]:
    return getattr(func, "__decorators__", [])


def is_decorated_by(func: AnyFunc, decorator: AnyFunc) -> bool:
    return decorator in get_decorators(func)


def test() -> None:
    def test_decorator_1(function: Callable[P, T]) -> Callable[P, T]:
        @wraps(function, test_decorator_1)
        def wrapper(*args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> T:
            print(f"Called wrapper from {test_decorator_1.__name__}")
            return function(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper

    def test_decorator_2(function: Callable[P, T]) -> Callable[P, T]:
        @wraps(function, test_decorator_2)
        def wrapper(*args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> T:
            print(f"Called wrapper from {test_decorator_2.__name__}")
            return function(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper

    @test_decorator_1
    @test_decorator_2
    def foo(x: str, y: int) -> None:
        print(x, y)

    assert get_decorators(foo) == [test_decorator_2, test_decorator_1]
    assert is_decorated_by(foo, test_decorator_1)
    assert hasattr(foo, "__wrapped__")
    foo("a", 1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

The output is of course:

```
Called wrapper from test_decorator_1
Called wrapper from test_decorator_2
a 1
```

#### Details and caveats

With this approach, none of the original functionality of `functools.wraps` should be lost. Just like the original, this `@wraps` decorator obviously relies on you passing the correct arguments for the entire affair to make sense in the end. If you pass a nonsense argument to `@wraps`, it will add nonsense information to your wrapper.

The difference is you now have to provide two function references instead of one, namely the function being wrapped (as before) and the outer decorator (or `None` if you want to suppress that information for some reason). So you would typically use it as `@wraps(function, decorator)`.

If you don't like that the `decorator` argument is mandatory, you could have it default to `None`. But I thought it was better this way, since the whole point is to have a consistent way of tracking who decorated whom, so omitting the `decorator` reference should be a conscious choice.

Note that I chose to implement `__decorators__` in that order because while they are written in the reverse order, they are **applied** in that order. So in this example `foo` is decorated with `@test_decorator_2` **first** and then the wrapper that comes out of that is decorated with `@test_decorator_1`. It made more sense to me for our list to reflect that order.

#### Static type checks

With the given type annotations `mypy --strict` is happy as well and any IDE should still provide the auto-suggestions as expected. The only thing that threw me off, was that `mypy` complained at my usage of `update_wrapper` as argument for `functools.partial`. I could not figure out, why that was, so I added a `# type: ignore` there.

**NOTE**: If you are on Python `<3.10`, you'll probably need to adjust the imports and take for example `ParamSpec` from `typing_extensions` instead. Also instead of `T | None`, you'll need to use [`typing.Optional[T]`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Optional) instead. Or upgrade your Python version.